# Отключить кэширование CSS стилей в Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, cms, кэширование

Добрый день!

Имеется сайт на Wordpress 4.2.2. Сайт клонирован на локальный сервер. В результате смены основного файла стилей изменения на сайте не отображаются. 
Заметил, что в теге link имеется параметр версии `?ver=4.2.2`. Отключил его при помощи найденного решения:

```
    // remove wp version param from any enqueued scripts
    function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
        if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
           $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
           return $src;
    }
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
```

Но это не помогло. Стили все равно кэшируются. В `header.php` шаблона нет явно указанного тега link.

```
    <? wp_head() ?>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/favicon.ico' ?>" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
      ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
      templateuri = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>';
    </script>
    <?php global $title ?>
```

Поэтому дописать `?1` к нужному стилю, как было указано в одном из решений на stackoverflow нельзя.

Сторонние плагины для кэширования страниц не используются.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли другие решения этого вопроса?

Comment: Скорее всего, браузер кэширует стили по указанию сервера. Проверьте заголовки которые отправляет и получает браузер при открытии css файла.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за скорый ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: В htaccess никаких инструкций насчет кэширования нет.

Comment: htaccess лишь изменяет стандартные настройки сервера. Вызовите консоль браузера и перейдите во вкладку Network или подобную ей, зависит от используемого браузера. После того как переключитесь в нее, перезагрузите страницу. В появившемся списке файлов выберете необходимый вам и по нажатии увидите подробную информацию. Скорее всего вы встретите заголовок Cache-Control:

Comment: Дмитрий, заголовок такой встретил, но значение у него другое, вот такое: Cache-Control:max-age=0

Comment: Покажите все заголовки.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин, https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9hce7jplspzlag/headers.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в файл .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header append Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

И обновите страницу с помощью комбинации клавиш ctrl+R

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Результат тот же, заголовки не изменились.

Comment: А в заголовках к данному css файлу в браузере появились значения, которые мы сейчас добавили?
"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"

Comment: Первый раз смотрел - не обратил внимания. Да, появились, но стили все равно не обновляются. Ссылка на скриншот: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9hce7jplspzlag/headers.png?dl=0

Comment: Все заработало! Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Частично решил проблему, включаю на браузере режим инкогнито, там кеш не хранится, на стадии разработки, вполне удобнор.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.